# Keras: How to create a custom Noisy Relu function?

Tags: python, neural-network, keras

How could I create a noisy Relu function in Keras?
Especially how do I create the noise Y~N(0,1).

```
def relu_noise(x):
return x*(x>0) + N(0,1)
```

Any ideas? Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a `Lambda` layer for that task.

Define a function normally, but using the [keras backend](https://keras.io/backend/) functions:

```
def relu_noise(x):

    isPositive = K.greater(x,0) 
    noise = K.random_normal((shape of x), mean=0.5, stddev=0.5)
         #I'm just not sure this is exactly the kind of noise you want. 

    return (x * isPositive) + noise
```

Then use it in a lambda layer:

```
from keras.layers import *

layer = Lambda(relu_noise, output_shape=(shape of x))
```

Add this layer to a `Sequential` model as any other layer, or call it with an input in a `Model`.

You can probably use it directly as an activation function as well:

```
layer = Dense(units, activation=relu_noise)
```